Верно ли поставлено тире?
Выключаю телефон и погружаюсь во мрак - экономлю свет, так как аккумулятор у телефона не вечный. Или всё же лучше заменить на двоеточие, так как после слов "погружаюсь во мрак" можно вставить "потому что"?

Правильно:
Выключаю телефон и погружаюсь во мрак — экономлю свет, так как аккумулятор у телефона не вечный.
Допустимый вариант:
Выключаю телефон и погружаюсь во мрак: экономлю свет, так как аккумулятор у телефона не вечный.
Пояснение

При постановке тире использована присоединительная конструкция со значением дополнительного пояснения. Здесь три  сказуемых, два из которых связаны союзом И, а третье обособлено как присоединительный член. Такой поход представляется вполне логичным.

Пример из Розенталя: § 24. Присоединительные конструкции. Внезапно мальчик исчез — умер, или, возможно, его похитили.

Можно рассмотреть конструкцию как БСП,  считая что у нас односоставные определенно-личные предложения. Тогда можно поставить присоединительное тире или пояснительное двоеточие.

Как выбрать? Надо учитывать контекст, а также произношение. При постановке двоеточия мы имеем интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю (неполное понижение голоса перед значительно увеличенной паузой). При постановке тире пауза меньше. Это тоже пояснение, но в присоединительном варианте, без задержки голоса.


